# CKAN resource labels as hyperlinks

Tags: ckan

I’m trying to customize/configure the CKAN resource labels on the main dataset page to include a hyperlink to the actual resource. For example, when I click on the “CSV” label on the datasets page, I would like to be prompted to download the file, rather than taking me to the dataset description page. Currently, I have to click on the title, which takes me to the description page, then click on the download button. Is there a plugin or some sort of customization I need to do in order to have this functionality?

Data.gov (e.g. http://catalog.data.gov/dataset) has the functionality I'm looking for.

Comment: Isn't there an 'Explore' button with a drop-down containing the Download link? e.g. http://demo.ckan.org/dataset/car-dataset

Comment: Yes, but I'm wondering if I can download the resource from the main dataset page (e.g. http://demo.ckan.org/dataset), instead of going the description page. For example, clicking on "XLS" allows me to download the resource, instead of taking me to the description page.

Comment: Ah, got you - the search results page.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a plugin or some sort of customization I need to do in order to have this functionality?

There is no extension that does this afaik. It sounds like a really small HTML change you could make easily.